# How to create a large jpeg image from svg image using macaw?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to create a high resolution image from a svg file.But i don't know how.Can i create it using macaw or there is another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Macaw is currently in beta and it has limitations. It can create high-resolution image but it is limited and also macaw can not render all SVG.
But macaw is so far the best svg renderer for ios till now and they have done some really magical things.

Answer (score 0):

SVG - is a vector format, it used in Android, but not iOS, so You can look for svg pods, like https://cocoapods.org/pods/SwiftSVG so You can add it in code directly

If You need it once - ask google "svg online converter" and convert it to png/pdf/jpg. For example: https://svgtopng.com

Comment: Sometimes you may need to work with vector images also I have mentioned already about macaw which is a swift library to work with svg in ios. Macaw has other benefit also. For details : https://github.com/exyte/Macaw

Comment: Yes, Macaw is like SwiftSVG or other libraries - it allow You to work with svg in iOS. 

I don't understand your question in this topic. Did You asked about different ways to work with swg? Or how to work with Macaw?

I tried to answer on the first question. If You need answer on the second - try to read https://github.com/exyte/Macaw/wiki/Getting-started#svg